# How to make a JButton not selected after clicking it?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, jtogglebutton

I have been created a delete button which delete some text from text field. 
But when I click this button and delete the text the button still selected.
I want to deselect this button after clicking it.

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
 private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jButton1.setSelected(false);
}
```

How to make a `JButton` not selected after clicking it?

Comment: You want to disable the button or return focus back to the field? Oh and I don't think a JToggleButton is what you wan to use...

Comment: i didn't want to disable the button, just make it not selected, or return the focus back to the field.  Any one work

Comment: Thanks  MadProgrammer

Comment: i will use jbutton rather than JToggleButton, and it work

Answer (score 1):

So, based on `jToggleButton1ActionPerformed`, I suspect you are using a `JToggleButton`, which has two states, selected and unselected, which probably isn't what you want.

Instead, just use a `JButton`

Answer (score 1):

```
jTextFieldN.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Be sure to read the [Java Docs for the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow--)..

---

Also, [as mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391301/418556) you'll need a `JButton` rather than `JToggleButton` for this.

Answer (score 0):

use a JButton and in the buttonClick event,

```
JButton.setEnabled(false);
```